# Installing spark on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, installation

I installed hadoop 2.7 on my mac. Then i want to install spark on it. But there is no any document for this.can anybody explain step by step how to install spark on hadoop?

Comment: If you like my answer, don't be tight-lipped ... pls vote/accept the answer as owner.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to Install Apache Spark

1)  Open Apache Spark Website http://spark.apache.org/

2)  Click on Downloads Tab a new Page will get open

3)  Choose Pre-built for Hadoop 2.7 and later

4)  Choose Direct Download

5)  Click on Download Spark: spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz  and save it on your desired location.

6)  Go to the Downloaded Tar file and Extract it.

7)  Again Extract the spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tar [File name will differ as version changes] to generate spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7 folder

8)  Now open Shell Prompt and go to the bin directory of spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7 folder [Folder name will differ as version changes ]

9)  Execute command spark-shell.sh

You will be in Spark Shell you can execute the spark commands

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html <-- Quick start Guide from spark

**Hope this Helps!!!**

Answer (score 0):

For running spark on yarn cluster there is lot of steps to install hadoop and spark and all so i write one blog on it step by step you can install it and run spark shell on yarn see the below link

https://blog.knoldus.com/2016/01/30/spark-shell-on-yarn-resource-manager-basic-steps-to-create-hadoop-cluster-and-run-spark-on-it/

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I took to install Apache Spark to a Linux Centos system with hadoop:

- Install a default Java system (ex: `sudo yum install java-11-openjdk`)
- Download latest release of Apache Spark from spark.apache.org
- Extract the Spark tarball (`tar xvf spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz`)
- Move Spark folder created after extraction to the /opt/ directory (`sudo mv spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/ /opt/spark`)
- Execute with command `/opt/spark/bin/spark-shell` if you wish to work with Scala or `/opt/spark/bin/pyspark` if you want to work with Python